# function "buttons disabled" from beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 Radio Buttons and 3 Buttons that each belong to 1 Radio Button. I want the Buttons only to be enabled if the according Radio Button is checked.

My code works, but only if I first click on a Radio Button and thus start the function. How can I make the function work, so that some buttons are disabled from the beginning?

The function looks like this

```
$("input:radio[name=Kartenthema]").change(function() {         
      if (this.value == "Geburtenrate") {
         $("#karte_id").attr('src', 'kantone_interaktiv_geburten.svg');
         $("#legende_id").attr('src', 'Legenden/GebLegende.PNG'); 
         $("input[name=button1]").attr("disabled", true);
         $("input[name=button1]").addClass("disabledClass");
         $("input[name=button2]").attr("disabled", false);
         $("input[name=button2]:enabled").removeClass("disabledClass");
         $("input[name=button3]").attr("disabled", true);
         $("input[name=button3]:disabled").addClass("disabledClass");
      } else if (this.value == "Sterberate") {
         $("#karte_id").attr('src', 'kantone_interaktiv_sterbe.svg');
         $("#legende_id").attr('src', 'Legenden/SterbLegende.PNG');
         $("input[name=button1]").attr("disabled", true);
         $("input[name=button1]:disabled").addClass("disabledClass");
         $("input[name=button2]").attr("disabled", true);
         $("input[name=button2]:disabled").addClass("disabledClass");
         $("input[name=button3]").attr("disabled", false);
         $("input[name=button3]:enabled").removeClass("disabledClass");
      } else if(this.value == "Wanderung") {
         $("#karte_id").attr('src', 'kantone_interaktiv_wanderung.svg');
         $("#legende_id").attr('src', 'Legenden/WandLegende.PNG');
         $("input[name=button1]").attr("disabled", false);
         $("input[name=button1]:enabled").removeClass("disabledClass");
         $("input[name=button2]").attr("disabled", true);
         $("input[name=button2]:disabled").addClass("disabledClass");
         $("input[name=button3]").attr("disabled", true);
         $("input[name=button3]:disabled").addClass("disabledClass")                            
      }  
}
```

And the Radio Buttons / Buttons look like this:

```
<embed id="legende_id" src="Legenden/GebLegende.PNG" width="180" height="230" style="margin-left:30px" type="image/PNG" />
<h3>
  <input type="radio" class="Radio" name="Kartenthema" value="Geburtenrate" checked="ckecked">Geburtenziffer
  <input type="button" class="Button" name="button2" value="Animation" onclick="location.href='animation_geburten.html'">
    <h3>
      <input type="radio" class="Radio" name="Kartenthema" value="Sterberate">Mortalität
      <input type="button" disabled="disabled" class="Button" name="button3" value="Animation" onclick="location.href='animation_mortalität.html'">
        <h3>
          <input type="radio" class="Radio" name="Kartenthema" value="Wanderung">Interkantonale Wanderung
          <input type="button" class="Button" name="button4" value="Animation" onclick="location.href='animation_wanderung.html'">
            <br>
              <br>
                <input type="button" class="Button" name="button1" value="Kartogramm" onclick="location.href='kartogramm.html'" />
              </br>
            </br>
          </input></input>
        </h3>
      </input></input>
    </h3>
  </input></input>
</h3>
```

I know that I can put a disabled after input type, but then the style doesn't change from enabled to disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (this.value == "Geburtenrate") {
```

Change this line and the next 2 similar lines to this:

```
  if ($(this).val() == "Geburtenrate") {
```

Comment: Change $("input:radio[name=Kartenthema]").change(function() {         
to $("input:radio[name=Kartenthema]").click(function() {

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, if the button styles are changing, what exactly are you referring to when you say "nothing happened"?

Comment: By "nothing happened" I mean the code still doesn't work like I want it to. 
The styles are changing when I click on the Radio Buttons, but there is only 1 style when I first open the homepage. The disabled buttons only change their style when I click on something, but they should look disabled from the beginning.
Sorry, it's pretty hard for me to describe the problem, as I have no coding knowledge and english is not my first language. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$("input[name=buttonN]").removeAttr("disabled")` to set controls enabled.

Answer (score 0):

No problem. Try changing your HTML code to this:

```
<h3>
<input type="radio" class="Radio" name="Kartenthema" value="Geburtenrate" checked="ckecked">Geburtenziffer
<input type="button" class="Button" name="button2" value="Animation" onclick="location.href='animation_geburten.html'" disabled="disabled">
</h3>
<h3>
<input type="radio" class="Radio" name="Kartenthema" value="Sterberate">Mortalität
<input type="button" disabled="disabled" class="Button" name="button3" value="Animation" onclick="location.href='animation_mortalität.html'">
</h3>
<h3>
<input type="radio" class="Radio" name="Kartenthema" value="Wanderung">Interkantonale Wanderung
<input type="button" class="Button" name="button4" value="Animation" onclick="location.href='animation_wanderung.html'" disabled="disabled">
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" class="Button" name="button1" value="Kartogramm" onclick="location.href='kartogramm.html'" disabled="disabled">
<br>
<br>
</h3>
```

Comment: I guess the only problem is that the style doesn't work right. Now the buttons are disabled when I open the page, but they still look enabled. The style only changes after the first click.

Comment: Do you want the "disabledClass" on each button every time the page loads? If that's what you require, simply change `class="Button"` to `class="Button disabledClass"` on all these buttons.

Comment: YES! Thank you so much! Now it works perfectly and just how I wanted :)